# Private v/s Public class properties in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, oop, public, private-members

Trying to make my OOP fundamentals strong based of objective C. Sorry if my explanation is too long.
I have 3 classes in my app as Class A, Class B and Class C objective C classes.
I have a property of class A in my implementation of class B i.e. it makes private property of class B.

```
// implementation Class B
@interface ClassB ()
  @property (nonatomic, strong) ClassA *classA;
@end
```

I create an instance of class B in one of my class C methods and try to access class A property through class B's instance in class C.

```
// implementation Class C
@interface ClassC ()
  @property (nonatomic, strong) ClassB *classB;
@end

@implementation ClassC
- (void)someMethod
{
  NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] init];
  classB = [[ClassB alloc] init];
  string = classB.classA.displayString; //get an error here - ClassB doesn't have classA.
}
@end
```

To avoid the error I moved the classA property from implementation to header in ClassB.

```
// header Class B
@interface ClassB : NSObject
  @property (nonatomic, strong) ClassA *classA;
@end
```

But I am worried that anybody class can create an instance of class B, access classA property and can then use/modify the properties which are part of class A.

***Question:*** Is it a good style to move the classA property to the header file of Class B so I can use it in Class C or should I create a method in Class B which returns me whatever I need from class A? Something like:

```
@implementation ClassB
- (NSString*)displayStringOfClassA
{
  classA = [[ClassA alloc] init];
  return self.classA.displayString;
}
@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest a readonly string property in `ClassB.h`.

ClassB.h:

```
@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSString *classAString;
```

ClassB.m:

```
- (NSString *) classAString
{
   return self.classA.displayString;
}
```

This acts as a "getter" method for the particular string you need, and avoids others getting access to classA.

Edit:

Others suggested adding classA as a readonly property in ClassB.h. This will still allow modification of classA properties, it will only guarantee that classA is not reassigned to another ClassA instance.

Comment: I am looking into how exactly readonly property works in objective C. If its true that readonly also allows modifications then I like your style of creating a method for string. But suppose Class A has 7 properties similar to display string and I want to access all of them, then it would be a lot of code to write methods for returning all 7 properties. P.s. I am not judging, just trying to learn more. :)

Comment: Readonly means that only the getter method will be visible, not the setter for that property. However, unless you make all of your properties readonly, setters will still exist for ClassA properties. So another class could do classB.classA.classAProperty = somethingThatYouDoNotWant;

Comment: I tried this out and you are true. Even readOnly can access other properties of classA and change it. In my Class C, I tried classB.classA.someOtherProperty = @"Change it" and it did accept and changed the property value.

Comment: If you want to protect properties of class A - make them readonly.

Comment: I suggested `readonly` for `classA` property because i missed that @tech_learning wants to protect ClassA properties. I edited answer already

Answer (score 3):

In ClassB.h:

```
@interface ClassB: NSObject
  @property (nonatomic, strong, readonly) ClassA *classA;
@end
```

In ClassB.m:

```
@interface ClassB()
  @property (nonatomic, strong, readwrite) ClassA *classA;
@end
```

Also, `strong` and `readwrite` are default modifiers - you can get rid of them. However, they improve code readability.
EDIT: if you want to forbid access for ClassA properties - do the same trick. Suggested above code will forbid only to modify classA property of classB. For ClassA's displayString:
 In ClassA.h:

```
@interface ClassA: NSObject
  @property (nonatomic, strong, readonly) NSString *displayString;
@end
```

In ClassA.m:

```
@interface ClassA()
  @property (nonatomic, strong, readwrite) NSString *displayString;
@end
```

Comment: Well, `strong` is default in ARC scope, `assign` in nonARC scope. Sure it's all about retainable types (objects). Is all okay now?

Comment: http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#property-declarations actually

Comment: To be clear, in ARC `strong` is the default semantic for object types, but `assign` is the default otherwise.

Comment: @Petro Korienev - Do you mean something like the one I modified in your answer above for ClassB.m?

Comment: If the one I modified is true, then it doesn't allow to forbid the access to classA properties. I tried it, and in classC is added some code to modified classA properties through classB instance and it did modify the property.

Comment: Not sure i'm following your question... I mean just this pattern (readonly in declaration, readwrite in extension) protects your class properties from undesired changing without writing any line of setter/getter. You can use it on every class that needs such protection.

Comment: One more time. Suggested code will protect only classB's classA property from mutation. Means you won't be able to classB.classA = [[ClassA alloc] init]. If you want to protect displayString - make it readonly on ClassA's level.

Comment: Edited to protect exactly displayString

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want "framework", not "private" `@property()` declarations.

To do this, create a file like:

ClassA_Private.h

That contains your `@property()` declaration.

Then `#import "ClassA_Private.h"` in both your `ClassA.m` (prior to the `@implementation`) and in any subclasses that want to use that `@property`.

This was a secondary design consideration when creation class extensions;  adding the ability to have `@property` declarations that are fully accessible across subclasses and/or within frameworks without being exposed externally.   While you can't create a framework for an iOS targeted application, the same functionality still applies.

Answer (score 0):

Something like `string = objectB.objectA.displayString;` is violating the [Law of Demeter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter). Designing according to the Law of Demeter results in more maintainable and adaptable software.

You should always try to *not talk to strangers*. That is in your example: `self` talks to `objectB` and `objectB` talks to `objectA` but `self` shouldn't talk to `objectA` because it's a stranger.